# Removing duplicates from a json object

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm looping through an json-like object and I'm trying to exclude a duplicate entry (the one with id:1) with no success. Here's my code:

```
var productData = '[{"id":1,"name":"Retro","price":10,"color":"blue"},{"id":2,"name":"Designer","price":12,"color":"red"},{"id":3,"name":"Classic","price":14,"color":"yellow"},{"id":1,"name":"Retro","price":10,"color":"blue"},{"id":4,"name":"Rimless","price":14,"color":"purple"},{"id":5,"name":"Glam & Sparkle","price":8,"color":"grey"}]',
    data = $.parseJSON(productData),
    table = $("#productTable"),
    dataFiltered = [];

$.each(data, function(key, value) {

    if ($.inArray(value.id, dataFiltered) === -1) {

        dataFiltered.push({"id": value.id, "price": value.price, "name": value.name,"color": value.color});


    }
});

console.log(dataFiltered)

$.each(dataFiltered, function(key, value) {
        table.append("<div class='row'><span>&pound;"+value.price+"</span>"+
                     "<span>"+value.name+"</span>"+"<span>"+value.color+
                     "</span></div>");
});
```

What am I doing wrong? It returns the same object with the duplicate entry in it. here's the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BP55H/97/) too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BP55H/116/)

Not sure whether this is the optimal way or not.. :)

```
var ids = []; 
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    if($.inArray(value.id, ids) === -1){
        ids.push(value.id);
        dataFiltered.push({"id": value.id, "price": value.price, "name": value.name,"color": value.color});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here: `$.inArray(value.id, dataFiltered)`.
`value.id` is an integer. `dataFiltered` is an array of objects.
`$.inArray` does this

```
for(i = 0; i < dataFiltered.length; i++) { 
    if(value.id === dataFiltered[i]) return 'found'; 
}
```

so it is comparing an integer to some objects. Obviously won't find anything ever.

What you need to do is implement a `find` function:

```
function arrayFind(a, v, check) {
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(check.call(this, a[i], v)) {
            return true; 
        }    
    }
    return false;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var findById = function(item, value) {
    return item.id === value;
};

if (arrayFind(dataFiltered, value.id, findById) === false) {
    .... 
}
```

Try looking at [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#find) for a more cool implementation.

Also, to better understand the difference, using my `arrayFind` implementation, your code would look like this:

```
var findById = function(item, value) {
    return item === value; // your issue is here
};

if (arrayFind(dataFiltered, value.id, findById) === false) {
    ....
}
```